# iOS: How can I prevent a resized view from resetting itself?

Tags: ios, uitableview, resize, ecslidingviewcontroller

I'm using [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController). When the app starts, it opens a scroll view which is resized dynamically, since it contains both labels and a table view. Both the table and the scroll view containing it are resized.

Everything works as intended when the view is first loaded. However, if I open and close the menu view, or if I use it to go to any view which resizes itself, the resizing does not work. Instead, it displays the scroll view as if it has the height assigned to it in the storyboard.

I'm completely lost as to why this happens, and would greatly appreciate help. I can post code as well, of course, but I don't know what code might help, since I guess that the error is on ECSlidingViewController's part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using auto layout? If so, whenever something else happens that triggers the application of the constraints, all the frames will be reset to the values dictated by those constraints. Try turning off auto layout and see if that fixes it. Refer to your [auto layout settings](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles/AutolayoutEnabling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009971-CH4-SW1).

Alternatively, if you want to keep auto layout, I'd generally suggest changing the frames by programmatically [changing the constant values of the constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16290912/1271826). But, I'm not familiar with `ECSlidingViewController`, so I don't know if that's a reasonable option in this particular case.

Comment: That was indeed the issue. Thank you very much!